# docusign send on behalf functionality

Tags: php, docusignapi

i am a newbie to docusign and api's in general. i have created a master account manually on docusign and now i want to create  new users using this account and use the send on behalf functionality. I have already gone through this pdf (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf). But can anyone explain in  layman's terms what are the exact steps that i need to follow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### April 2021 Update

Neither SOBO nor Legacy Authentication is supported for new REST API integrations. Instead, use an OAuth v2.0 authentication grant. The replacement for the SOBO pattern is to use the JWT grant which enables the application to impersonate any DocuSign user who has given consent to the application to do so. Open a new q here on StackOverflow if you have questions.

### Original answer

Please go through the [DocuSign Dev Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center) as there is some very useful information throughout the site, including the exact SOBO (Send On Behalf Of) steps that you are looking for.

Go to Dev Center -> Explore -> Features -> SOBO.  Generally speaking these are steps you need to take:

1. Obtain an access token for User1 (the authenticating user)
2. Obtain an access token for User2 (the operating user - you're sending on behalf of this person)
3. Send Request on behalf of User2

See this page of the Dev Center for the exact steps to take and potential account settings you need to have turned on:

http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo

---

To summarize what the page explains and have the answer here too, here are the details:

STEP #1:

```
POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/oauth2/token

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: {length of body}

grant_type=password&client_id={IntegratorKey}&username={email}&password={password}&scope=api
```

Make sure you supply your account email, password, and integrator key in the body.

A successful response returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "access_token": "<access token for user>",
    "scope": "api",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

STEP #2:

Here you add the header `Authorization: bearer <access_token>` where `<access_token>` is the token that was returned in step 1 and the email is now the email address of the user you want to send on behalf of:

```
POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/oauth2/token

Authorization: bearer <access token>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: {length of body}
 
grant_type=password&client_id={IntegratorKey}&username={$emailOnBehalf}&password={password}&scope=api
```

The result is another access token, let's say it's 12345.

Step #3:

Now you can send on behalf of this user by using the following auth headers in your signature request:

```
Authorization: bearer 12345
X-DocuSign-Act-As-User: $emailOnBehalf
```

Comment: For some reason this link doesn't work - http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo. It keeps me taking back to the generic home page "https://developers.docusign.com". Anyone with updates?

Comment: The SOBO feature has been deprecated, use-cases like this are now handled more securely using OAuth.  Look at the obtaining consent section for OAuth, do a search for `impersonation` and you'll see the params you need to set to access someone else's account:  https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent