# Unattended authorization into API - no longer possible?

Tags: docusignapi

A brief investigation shows that there once existed an authorization mode known as SOBO (for example, see [docusign send on behalf functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763208/docusign-send-on-behalf-functionality)), which I find useful in a scenario when an application associates signing requests not with a logged-on user but with some other user. However I am unable to find any mention of it in current documentation; on the contrary, documentation clearly says only 3 grant types are supported, and all three involve impersonated user's actively expressing his consent. No way to just send user credentials, or, alternatively, have user express his consent just once on the docusign admin page, then reuse that consent for, say, one year or forever. Or some other way to avoid end user interaction.

Also, a requirement of using redirect URI to send back continuation data implies one has to either use on-premise solution or make one's application visible on the internet. No way to use public docusign service with on-premise application, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign is discouraging Legacy Header authentication because it requires your integration to hold on to the user's plain-text password. It also cannot support accounts that leverage Single-Sign On or Two-Factor Authentication. The long-term plan is likely to eventually retire it entirely, but there's no timeline for that. Documentation has been retired, but integrations that have used it in the past can still do so.

JWT auth is the equivalent replacement. With individual consent, a user grants the integration access once. Unless the user revokes that consent, the integration will be able to generate access tokens to act as the user indefinitely - JWT consent does not expire.

If you have an Organization with a Claimed Domain, an org admin can grant blanket consent to allow an integration to act as any user under that domain. If you'd like to grant consent to an integrator key owned by your organization, it's as simple as navigating to Org Admin > Applications > Authorize Application. Granting consent to a 3rd party app is similar to the Individual Consent workflow, but has extra scopes as documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent

Note that while JWT auth does require a redirect URI to be registered, an integration doesn't necessarily need to 'catch' the user after they've granted consent. While it would be recommended that the landing page trigger the user to move forward in the workflow, it's acceptable to point your redirect URI to https://www.example.com, grant consent, and then generate an access token.